# When is it safe to call $setPristine?

Tags: angularjs

I have some code that initializes a form (fairly complex initialization).  I want to call it when the form is first displayed, but  I'm having to do something like this:

```
        if($scope.callForm) {
            $scope.callForm.$setPristine();
        }
```

Because at the time the controller is being initialized, angular hasn't gotten around to creating the ng-form named callForm.  All the rest of my initialization is done, I had added the $setPristine() so that it would reset if the user clicks the **New** button.  It isn't actually needed at startup since the form will come up pristine

The code above will work, but is there some promise I could wait on to do the initialization, so that angular has instantiated all the DOM stuff before my controller code performs its initialization?  Just trying to keep a heads up for other race conditions.  Angular 1.2.9

Comment: Watch on the variable `callForm` and on first initialization set it to pristine.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that, excellent Idea

Comment: Why not just call $setPristine in the click handler for the New button?

Comment: $setPristine is in a function that is used to initialize the form.  That function is called when the user clicks the new button.  It is also called when I load the form on a deep link to create a new item.  The problem with the latter case is the form isn't angularized yet, so I have to skip that part due to angular not be "ready".

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-init="someFunctionSettingPristingState()" and put it on form tag, so this will be called only when angularjs start initializing the form...

i havent tested it though.